# sbt task to increment project version

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there an SBT task to increment a project's version?

Given an initial configuration of something like the following *build.sbt*

```
name := 'My Project'

organization := 'org.example'

version := '0.1.0'
```

and a versioning nomenclature of *major.minor.patch*, I was hoping for an SBT task like

```
> incrementVersionPatch
```

that would result in a version of `0.1.1`.

(Ideally also the corresponding `incrementVersionMinor` and `incrementVersionMajor`.)

I feel like this must already exist but cannot find a way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you need is [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) plugin that *"provides a customizable release process that you can add to your project."* with *"the setting `release-version-file`, which is set to `file("version.sbt")` by default and points to `$PROJECT_ROOT/version.sbt`"*.

Comment: Can you point me to an example? release-version-file doesn't seem to be working in sbt 0.13.15 & sbt-release 1.0.5

Comment: sbt-release does a bunch of things, only one of them is what is asked for here.  So if you already have a release process and *just* want to bump the version, it's not super helpful unfortunately.